How do I get it to show the Stage manager icon in my app?
screenshot
I tried to write an anniversary app for my angora rabbit using swift UI, but I can't set the icon on this image.
    @objc func didCreateWindow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
            // 设置窗口标题
            window.title = "兔可可的纪念日啊"
            // 设置窗口图标
            if let iconImage = NSImage(named: "AppIcon") {
                window.standardWindowButton(.documentIconButton)?.image = iconImage
            } else {
                print("图标加载失败")
            }
        }
    }

I'm not doing a lot in the code, just the bare minimum of displaying content on the interface.

Does your App Icon show up in the Dock?

Yes I think you should be adding an app icon to the assets folder to make this work.
